# Persist only base class's fields at hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have a base class and some class which extends the base class.
Due to the fields of the extending class used for other purpose and for the db, I want to persist only the base class field, how can I do it? Is there an annotation that do it?
Note that I don't want to use @Transient for each new field I crate.

Comment: What happens if you only annotate the superclass as an `@Entity`, and not the subclasses?

Comment: It's problem when i'll try to persist child class. I want that when I persist child class it's persist only the base fields.

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to persist only base class object just create base class entity instead of child class entity and save.**

Comment: If I have base class with @Entity and @Inheritance(strategy= InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE), how can I do it? I'll get exception?

Comment: another point - how can I get the base class when I persist?  is there a annotation at hibernate which persist only certain fields?

Comment: @eliran  If you want topersist only base class fields so I think @Inheritance(strategy= InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE) is not required.

Comment: If you want to persist only base class fields so I think @Inheritance(strategy= InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE) is not required.for getting base class you need to explicitly create base class entity from your object.I have never used any annotation (except  @Transient on each child field) which will only save base class fields in inheritance.As per my thinking it is a bit contradictory,I am applying inheritance as well as I want to save only base class field.